# Grunt. Convert json file to javascript file and store json file data into js object

Tags: javascript, json, gruntjs, yaml

I have yaml files with localization strings on the server. I'm using grunt and grunt-yaml module to convert yaml files to json files. The problem is that I need to store those file in the head section of the page like js files and pass it into variable. Example:
I have json

```
{
    en: {
        name: "Name",
        ......
    }
}
```

And I need to convert it to js file and include it to using script tag:

```
var language = {
        en: {
            name: "Name",
            ......
        }
    }
<script type="text/javascript" src="path-to-file/en.js"></script>
```

In that way I will have access to json in my application.

**Note!** I can't load json via ajax, because of technical reasons. I need to form file url based on the serverside logic.

Best solution is to use some other grunt module to convert yaml directly to js file with json in it. Or use one more module to convert json file to needed js.

Anyway, I don't know if it even possible. If no, I will use grails for conversion.

Comment: If you are interested i can provide you a way of doing it (can tell you only the algorithm for that  .. you will still have to code it yourself)!!